# Prevent clear button to wipe hidden fields

Tags: forms, orbeon

We use hidden fields to display initial information in the form.
We explicitly do not want to use http requests. The form should contain all information after sending the form data via CRUD-API to the server.

The problem is that the clear button also clears the hidden fields and our initial information is wiped.
I also tried to design my own process, but I was not able to make it work.

Is it possible to configure the clear button or designing a custom process to leave the hidden fields untouched?

Comment: How are you setting the value of those hidden fields? You says that you don't want to use an HTTP request, so maybe that isn't with an HTTP Service and Action, but you are using a calculation? Or maybe something else? -Alex

Comment: I'm filling the data.xml externally (IBM i) with the needed information:
1. Step: GET: /orbeon/fr/service/persistence/crud/$app/$form/data/$doc/data.xml
2. Step: Fill hidden fields in data.xml with information out of our system
3. Step: PUT: /orbeon/fr/service/persistence/crud/$app/$form/data/$doc/data.xml

In the form I'm using Template Parameters to fill an Explanatory-Text-Control with the values out of the prefilled hidden fields.

Comment: Got it. Would reloading the data from the database work your use case? I.e. any unsaved changes would be "cleared", but if users changed the value of a field, and saved, then that change would still be there. (I don't think we can do much better than that, as otherwise how could we distinguish between changes that *you* put in the data "externally" and changes saved by users, so you could "clear" on the latter?) -Alex

Comment: That would help. I would assume, that the user doesn't want to wipe his intentionally saved data anyway. So how could I archive this database reload by clicking a button? Unfortunately I am not able to determine the correct action to use.

Comment: Perfect, since reloading data from the database works for your use case, and that reloading the webpage would do that, I provided an answer below how to do this using a process. You will let me know how this works for you! -Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that what you are after, based on your comments, is to reload data that was previously saved in the database. This is what reloading the current webpage would achieve, and you can instruct the *Clear* button to do so by defining the following process:

```
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.detail.process.clear.*.*">
    navigate(uri = "javascript:window.location.reload(true)")
</property>
```